# Solving more complex diferential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've come up with this implicit equation

$ (y')^2(2x-2x^2+2y^2)+(y')^2=1 $

and I'd like to find the function $y(x)$ (so that it's definition doesn't contain it's derivative).
Only thing I've been able to come up with is to see if f is polynomial. I calculated that if it were, it's degree (?) would have to be 1 or 3. Trying to solve for both of those resulted in a system with no solutions.

Now I'm stuck.
I'm aware that the solution might not be unique but since this isn't a set problem but something I came up with, I can provide any parameters that are required. WolframAlpha said something about $y(0)=1$ so if that's one of the required parameters, that's fine.

Comment: What do you mean by the function f? You have x's and y's in there.

Comment: Oh. Sorry. I meant the function $y(x)$

Comment: Do you mean to have two copies of $(y')^2$ in the equation? Because it would seem natural to then factor $(y')^2$ out of it entirely, then have an explicit formula for $y'$ after taking squareroot, making it a matter of integrating something.

Comment: Sure. You can do that. I've tried but I don't know how to integrate implicit functions. In that square root, there's a $2y^2$ I don't know what to do with.